# iPhone 7 Frozen Can't turn off or Reset

Tags: performance, iphone

My iPhone 7 just frozen right after the Passcode was entered. So basically it's frozen on the home screen right before the apps animates / slides in on the home screen.

I've tried holding the sleep / wake button + home button down with no luck. Nothing happens. I'm able to slide down the notification center and type and search in the box but then I try to open an app nothing happens.

If I press and hold to activate Siri, she appears for a second then turns off as if I pressed the home button again.

I've tried connecting the iPhone to a Mac but as it's Passcode enabled it tells me to unlock it and then replug it which I'm not able to do.

Any idea on how I can move forward? 
I could wait for the battery to drain but since it's at 91% it will take a while and I was hoping for a quicker fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force shutdown the iPhone 7 you need to hold volume down button and the sleep/wake button.

Answer (score 0):

hold down the Volume/down button and the Sleep/wake button at the same time until it restarts again, then let both go.
When that does not solve it: the same again, but only let go of the Sleepwake button when you see the apple start symbol. Then a connect to iTunes symbol appears. then connect to iTunes and restore the iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

I made a Quick Video Guide on  How My Iphone 7 will not Turn off! FIXED!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI6kxsy6vM8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future (although I appreciate it's a video you've made and probably intend to keep online). Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to also include a summary of what you've done? This will help preserve your answer for other users who may benefit in future.